# Correct this solution to finding $||A||$ of $(Af)(x) = g(x)f(x)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I need some help with a question I tried to solve it, but I am just not quite sure if my answer is correct. (I have got the feeling it can be - much - better).

Suppose we have a complex Hilbert space $H:= L^2(-1,2)$, with the standard norm. Futhermore, we have got the linear map $A: H\rightarrow H$ defined by $$(Af)(x) = g(x)f(x), \text {with } g, f\in H$$
Note that $g$ is bounded on the given interval. Now I have to show $A$ is bounded and find $||A||$.

**First:** I show $A$ is bounded. $$\begin{align}||(Af)(x)|| = ||g(x)f(x)|| & = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{2} |g(t)f(t)|^2 dt} \\
& \leq (\max_{x^*\in[-1,2]}|g(x^*)|)\sqrt{\int_{-1}^2 |f(t)|^2 dt} \\ &= (\max_{x^*\in[-1,2]}|g(x^*)|) ||f(x)||\end{align}.$$
So $||A||\leq \max_{x^*\in[-1,2]}|g(x^*)|$, where I used the fact that $|g(x)f(x)|\leq (\max_{x^*\in[-1,2]}|g(x^*)|)|f(x)|$.
So $A$ is bounded and we have to find $||A||\geq M$ with $M$ being a real value.

**Second:**(*duplicate of one*) Now we have to find $$||A|| = \sup_{f\in H}\frac{||(Af)(x)||}{||f||} = \sup_{||f||=1}^{x\in[-1,2]} ||(Af)(x)|| \leq \max_{x^*\in[-1,2]}|g(x^*)||f(x)||$$ 
and so $||A|| = \max_{x^*\in[-1,2]}|g(x^*)|$.

Is this any good or not?

Comment: Note that for $A$ to be well defined, you need $g\in H$ (take $f=1$). Your second part is not clear to me. In particular the second equality in your equation.

Comment: So when $g(x) = i x \in H$ in this case, so what you are saying is basically the answer to my last note right?
Futhermore the second part is to find a lower bound of $||A||$ and I thought of just using $||(Af)(x)||\leq ||A|| ||f||$, but if it is not clear then may be it could be wrong.

Comment: No what I mean is that if you want $A$ to be well defined on $H$ you need to have $g\in H$ (no matter how you choose it). Now, a lower bound on $\|A\|$ is "easy" to find. As you noticed, we have $\|A\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Af\|$ and so you you can compute $\|Af\|$ for any $f\in H$ with $\|f\|=1$ to get a lower bound. Getting the largest lower bound (i.e. computing $\|A\|$) is a different story though.

Comment: @xpnerd: your arguments use that $g $ is bounded, but you don't have that as a hypothesis. And you need that assumption, because otherwise  $A $ is not necessarily  bounded.  Also, your "second" is just a rewrite of your "first", so it adds no new information.

Comment: Ok, I will correct that part of $g$ being bounded. When I have corrected that, am I right on the first part?As for the second part, I am correct with saying that I have to find $||A||\geq M$ right? If so, how should I do the second part?

Comment: Two remarks: 1. Being bounded does not imply that the maximum you write down exists (only the supremum). 2. Even with the maximum replaced by the supremum, your second claim is not true in general. You have to take the essential supremum.

Comment: With the essential supremum being dependent of your $g$. So what if $g(x) = i x$, then $||A|| = 2$? (although my second part is still completely wrong).